# Incompatible datatypes text and nvarchar in the equal to operator

Tags: c#, sql-server

> The data types text and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

I got this message from number of times in my login page. How to handle this problem?

```
class loginDAL
{
    static string myconnstrng = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstrng"].ConnectionString;
    public bool loginCheck(loginBLL l)
    {
        bool isSuccess = true;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstrng);

        try
        {
            string sql = "SELECT *  FROM tbl_users WHERE username=@username AND password=@password AND user_type=@user_type";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", l.username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", l.password);
            //I got error on this next line
            **cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_type", l.user_type);**

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                isSuccess = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isSuccess = false;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return isSuccess;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: + `conn.Open()`..?

Comment: show us the class structure for `loginBLL` and SQL dataType for `user_type`

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ANYSTORE.BLL
{
    class loginBLL
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string user_type { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: and what is the SQL Datatype for `user_type` column?

Comment: I would suggest to edit the question and add Table Schema, and Class Definition

Comment: sir can i share you actual problem via email if possible?

Comment: yes you can....

Comment: I create one billing system which i have given two user type like admin and user . In admin user_type i provide details of admin login and In user user_type i provide details of user login  .In that login form after entering values as username password and user type after i click on login button that error comes out :
"The data types text and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator."

Comment: You can share the overall code to my mail Id will check

Comment: ok sir plz send your mail id

Comment: prashantpimpale93@gmail.com